# Combine 2 queries in the same result

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using oracle sql and I need help.
I have 2 tables, one that as bills and another that as receipts. I have to present both bills and receipts in the same result, using the same columns to show the info. 
For example:

```
Columns:  Date      - Time  - Number - Reference - Debit - Credit
Bill   : 25/05/2015 - 18:00 -   50   -  (empty)  - 500   -  0
Receipt: 25/05/2015 - 18:00 - (empty)-  Bill: 50 -  0    - 500
```

I have the query for the bill table and I'm creating the other for the receipt table but I don't know how to 'merge' them.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Update:
I'm adding this here because it's part of this problem.
My receipts table doesn't have all the information that i need to present, 'Reference', 'Debit', 'Credit'

For me to present that info I have to read it from other tables, including the table of my bills and I have started doing it and I have checked the cost that the query was having and it was huge, 5890. As for the bills query it only has a cost of 13.

Is there a way to reduce the cost?

Comment: You would "merge" them using `union all`.  Please show your current queries if you want more help than that.

Comment: My guess is that you're looking for `UNION ALL`.  But it's not completely clear.

Comment: presumably you want to show bills and receipts for the same order/transaction - is there a column with a transaction or order number in either table?

Answer (score 0):

UNION ALL operator is used to combine the result sets of 2 or more SELECT statements. It returns all rows from the query (even if the row exists in more than one of the SELECT statements).

```
SELECT *
FROM bills
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM receipts;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL as previously suggested but keep in mind the columns should be exactly the same for UNION ALL to work.

Comment: The column _names_ are irrelevant for `UNION` (or `UNION ALL`) - the data types are important.